# Awk not working, but has done in the past?

Tags: awk

Thanks in advance for your help with this.

I am trying to run the below awk command, however, it's not working. I've run the exact command before on a number of expressions, and this has worked fine. I have even tried to run with just 5 expressions, but it is still not working. any ideas?

I want to remove all lines with the expressions listed in column 5. If I can't get awk to work, whats an alternative, and could you give the command for this.

Many thanks in advance.

> awk '$5 !~/^(HG00403|HG00404|HG00406|HG00407|HG00409|HG00410|HG00419|HG00421|HG00422|HG00428|HG00436|HG00437|HG00442|HG00443|HG00445|HG00446|HG00448|HG00449|HG00451|HG00452|HG00457|HG00458|HG00463|HG00464|HG00472|HG00473|HG00475|HG00476|HG00478|HG00479|HG00500|HG00513|HG00524|HG00525|HG00530|HG00531|HG00533|HG00534|HG00536|HG00537|HG00542|HG00543|HG00551|HG00553|HG00554|HG00556|HG00557|HG00559|HG00560|HG00565|HG00566|HG00580|HG00581|HG00583|HG00584|HG00589|HG00590|HG00592|HG00593|HG00595|HG00596|HG00598|HG00599|HG00607|HG00608|HG00610|HG00611|HG00613|HG00614|HG00619|HG00620|HG00622|HG00623|HG00625|HG00626|HG00628|HG00629|HG00631|HG00632|HG00634|HG00637|HG00638|HG00640|HG00641|HG00650|HG00651|HG00653|HG00654|HG00656|HG00657|HG00662|HG00663|HG00671|HG00672|HG00674|HG00675|HG00683|HG00684|HG00689|HG00690|HG00692|HG00693|HG00698|HG00699|HG00701|HG00704|HG00705|HG00707|HG00708|HG00717|HG00728|HG00729|HG00731|HG00732|HG00734|HG00736|HG00737|HG00739|HG00740|HG00742|HG00743|HG00759|HG00766|HG00844|HG00851|HG00864|HG00867|HG00879|HG00881|HG00956|HG00978|HG00982|HG01028|HG01029|HG01031|HG01046|HG01047|HG01048|HG01049|HG01051|HG01052|HG01054|HG01055|HG01058|HG01060|HG01061|HG01063|HG01064|HG01066|HG01067|HG01069|HG01070|HG01072|HG01073|HG01075|HG01077|HG01079|HG01080|HG01082|HG01083|HG01085|HG01086|HG01088|HG01089|HG01092|HG01094|HG01095|HG01097|HG01098|HG01101|HG01102|HG01104|HG01105|HG01107|HG01108|HG01110|HG01111|HG01112|HG01113|HG01119|HG01121|HG01122|HG01124|HG01125|HG01130|HG01131|HG01133|HG01134|HG01136|HG01137|HG01139|HG01140|HG01142|HG01148|HG01149|HG01161|HG01162|HG01164|HG01167|HG01168|HG01170|HG01171|HG01173|HG01174|HG01176|HG01177|HG01182|HG01183|HG01187|HG01188|HG01190|HG01191|HG01197|HG01198|HG01200|HG01204|HG01205|HG01241|HG01242|HG01247|HG01248|HG01250|HG01251|HG01253|HG01254|HG01256|HG01257|HG01259|HG01260|HG01269|HG01271|HG01272|HG01275|HG01277|HG01280|HG01281|HG01284|HG01286|HG01302|HG01303|HG01305|HG01308|HG01311|HG01312|HG01323|HG01325|HG01326|HG01341|HG01342|HG01344|HG01345|HG01348|HG01350|HG01351|HG01353|HG01354|HG01356|HG01357|HG01359|HG01360|HG01362|HG01363|HG01365|HG01366|HG01369|HG01372|HG01374|HG01375|HG01377|HG01378|HG01383|HG01384|HG01389|HG01390|HG01392|HG01393|HG01395|HG01396|HG01398|HG01402|HG01403|HG01405|HG01412|HG01413|HG01414|HG01431|HG01432|HG01435|HG01437|HG01438|HG01440|HG01441|HG01443|HG01444|HG01447|HG01455|HG01456|HG01459|HG01461|HG01462|HG01464|HG01465|HG01468|HG01474|HG01479|HG01485|HG01486|HG01488|HG01489|HG01491|HG01492|HG01494|HG01495|HG01497|HG01498|HG01550|HG01551|HG01556|HG01565|HG01566|HG01571|HG01572|HG01577|HG01578|HG01583|HG01586|HG01589|HG01593|HG01595|HG01596|HG01597|HG01598|HG01599|HG01600|HG01794|HG01795|HG01796|HG01797|HG01798|HG01799|HG01800|HG01801|HG01802|HG01804|HG01805|HG01806|HG01807|HG01808|HG01809|HG01810|HG01811|HG01812|HG01813|HG01815|HG01816|HG01817|HG01840|HG01841|HG01842|HG01843|HG01844|HG01845|HG01846|HG01847|HG01848|HG01849|HG01850|HG01851|HG01852|HG01853|HG01855|HG01857|HG01858|HG01859|HG01860|HG01861|HG01862|HG01863|HG01864|HG01865|HG01866|HG01867|HG01868|HG01869|HG01870|HG01871|HG01872|HG01873|HG01874|HG01878|HG01879|HG01880|HG01882|HG01883|HG01885|HG01886|HG01889|HG01890|HG01892|HG01893|HG01894|HG01896|HG01912|HG01914|HG01915|HG01917|HG01918|HG01920|HG01921|HG01923|HG01924|HG01926|HG01927|HG01932|HG01933|HG01935|HG01936|HG01938|HG01939|HG01941|HG01942|HG01944|HG01945|HG01947|HG01948|HG01950|HG01951|HG01953|HG01954|HG01956|HG01958|HG01961|HG01965|HG01967|HG01968|HG01970|HG01971|HG01973|HG01974|HG01976|HG01977|HG01979|HG01980|HG01982|HG01985|HG01986|HG01988|HG01989|HG01990|HG01991|HG01992|HG01997|HG02002|HG02003|HG02006|HG02008|HG02009|HG02010|HG02012|HG02013|HG02014|HG02016|HG02017|HG02019|HG02020|HG02023|HG02025|HG02026|HG02028|HG02029|HG02031|HG02032|HG02035|HG02040|HG02047|HG02048|HG02049|HG02050|HG02051|HG02052|HG02053|HG02054|HG02057|HG02058|HG02060|HG02061|HG02064|HG02067|HG02069|HG02070|HG02072|HG02073|HG02075|HG02076|HG02078|HG02079|HG02081|HG02082|HG02084|HG02085|HG02086|HG02087|HG02088|HG02089|HG02090|HG02095|HG02102|HG02104|HG02105|HG02107|HG02108|HG02111|HG02113|HG02116|HG02121|HG02122|HG02127|HG02128|HG02130|HG02131|HG02133|HG02134|HG02136|HG02137|HG02138|HG02139|HG02140|HG02141|HG02142|HG02143|HG02144|HG02146|HG02147|HG02150|HG02151|HG02152|HG02153|HG02154|HG02155|HG02156|HG02164|HG02165|HG02166|HG02178|HG02179|HG02180|HG02181|HG02182|HG02184|HG02185|HG02186|HG02187|HG02188|HG02190|HG02250|HG02252|HG02253|HG02255|HG02256|HG02259|HG02260|HG02262|HG02265|HG02266|HG02271|HG02272|HG02274|HG02275|HG02277|HG02278|HG02281|HG02282|HG02283|HG02284|HG02285|HG02286|HG02291|HG02292|HG02298|HG02299|HG02301|HG02304|HG02307|HG02308|HG02309|HG02312|HG02314|HG02315|HG02317|HG02318|HG02322|HG02323|HG02325|HG02330|HG02332|HG02334|HG02337|HG02339|HG02343|HG02345|HG02348|HG02351|HG02353|HG02355|HG02356|HG02360|HG02364|HG02367|HG02371|HG02373|HG02374|HG02375|HG02379|HG02380|HG02382|HG02383|HG02384|HG02385|HG02386|HG02389|HG02390|HG02391|HG02392|HG02394|HG02395|HG02396|HG02397|HG02398|HG02399|HG02401|HG02402|HG02406|HG02407|HG02408|HG02409|HG02410|HG02419|HG02420|HG02425|HG02427|HG02429|HG02433|HG02439|HG02442|HG02445|HG02449|HG02450|HG02455|HG02461|HG02462|HG02464|HG02465|HG02470|HG02471|HG02476|HG02477|HG02479|HG02481|HG02484|HG02485|HG02489|HG02490|HG02491|HG02493|HG02494|HG02496|HG02497|HG02501|HG02502|HG02505|HG02508|HG02511|HG02512|HG02513|HG02521|HG02522|HG02536|HG02537|HG02541|HG02545|HG02546|HG02549|HG02554|HG02555|HG02557|HG02558|HG02561|HG02562|HG02568|HG02570|HG02571|HG02573|HG02574|HG02577|HG02580|HG02582|HG02583|HG02585|HG02586|HG02588|HG02589|HG02594|HG02595|HG02597|HG02600|HG02601|HG02603|HG02604|HG02610|HG02611|HG02613|HG02614|HG02620|HG02621|HG02623|HG02624|HG02628|HG02629|HG02634|HG02635|HG02642|HG02643|HG02645|HG02646|HG02648|HG02649|HG02651|HG02652|HG02654|HG02655|HG02657|HG02658|HG02660|HG02661|HG02666|HG02667|HG02675|HG02676|HG02678|HG02679|HG02681|HG02682|HG02684|HG02685|HG02687|HG02688|HG02690|HG02691|HG02694|HG02696|HG02697|HG02699|HG02700|HG02702|HG02703|HG02715|HG02716|HG02721|HG02722|HG02724|HG02725|HG02727|HG02728|HG02731|HG02733|HG02734|HG02736|HG02737|HG02756|HG02757|HG02759|HG02760|HG02763|HG02768|HG02769|HG02771|HG02772|HG02774|HG02775|HG02778|HG02780|HG02783|HG02784|HG02786|HG02787|HG02789|HG02790|HG02792|HG02793|HG02798|HG02799|HG02804|HG02805|HG02807|HG02808|HG02810|HG02811|HG02813|HG02814|HG02816|HG02817|HG02819|HG02820|HG02836|HG02837|HG02839|HG02840|HG02851|HG02852|HG02854|HG02855|HG02860|HG02861|HG02870|HG02878|HG02879|HG02881|HG02882|HG02884|HG02885|HG02887|HG02888|HG02890|HG02891|HG02895|HG02896|HG02922|HG02923|HG02938|HG02941|HG02943|HG02944|HG02946|HG02947|HG02952|HG02953|HG02968|HG02970|HG02971|HG02973|HG02974|HG02976|HG02977|HG02979|HG02981|HG02982|HG02983|HG03006|HG03007|HG03009|HG03012|HG03015|HG03016|HG03018|HG03019|HG03021|HG03022|HG03024|HG03025|HG03027|HG03028|HG03039|HG03040|HG03045|HG03046|HG03048|HG03049|HG03052|HG03054|HG03055|HG03057|HG03058|HG03060|HG03061|HG03063|HG03064|HG03066|HG03069|HG03072|HG03073|HG03074|HG03077|HG03078|HG03079|HG03081|HG03082|HG03084|HG03085|HG03086|HG03088|HG03091|HG03095|HG03096|HG03097|HG03099|HG03100|HG03103|HG03105|HG03108|HG03109|HG03111|HG03112|HG03114|HG03115|HG03117|HG03118|HG03120|HG03121|HG03123|HG03124|HG03126|HG03127|HG03129|HG03130|HG03132|HG03133|HG03135|HG03136|HG03139|HG03157|HG03159|HG03160|HG03162|HG03163|HG03166|HG03168|HG03169|HG03172|HG03175|HG03189|HG03190|HG03193|HG03195|HG03196|HG03198|HG03199|HG03202|HG03209|HG03212|HG03224|HG03225|HG03228|HG03229|HG03234|HG03235|HG03237|HG03238|HG03240|HG03241|HG03246|HG03247|HG03258|HG03259|HG03265|HG03267|HG03268|HG03270|HG03271|HG03279|HG03280|HG03291|HG03294|HG03295|HG03297|HG03298|HG03300|HG03301|HG03303|HG03304|HG03311|HG03313|HG03342|HG03343|HG03351|HG03352|HG03354|HG03363|HG03366|HG03367|HG03369|HG03370|HG03372|HG03376|HG03378|HG03380|HG03382|HG03385|HG03388|HG03391|HG03394|HG03397|HG03401|HG03410|HG03419|HG03428|HG03432|HG03433|HG03436|HG03437|HG03439|HG03442|HG03445|HG03446|HG03449|HG03451|HG03452|HG03455|HG03457|HG03458|HG03460|HG03461|HG03464|HG03469|HG03470|HG03472|HG03473|HG03476|HG03478|HG03479|HG03484|HG03485|HG03488|HG03490|HG03491|HG03499|HG03511|HG03514|HG03515|HG03517|HG03518|HG03520|HG03521|HG03538|HG03539|HG03547|HG03548|HG03556|HG03557|HG03558|HG03559|HG03563|HG03565|HG03567|HG03571|HG03572|HG03575|HG03577|HG03578|HG03583|HG03585|HG03589|HG03593|HG03594|HG03595|HG03598|HG03600|HG03603|HG03604|HG03607|HG03611|HG03615|HG03616|HG03619|HG03624|HG03625|HG03629|HG03631|HG03634|HG03636|HG03640|HG03642|HG03643|HG03644|HG03645|HG03646|HG03649|HG03652|HG03653|HG03660|HG03663|HG03667|HG03668|HG03672|HG03673|HG03679|HG03680|HG03681|HG03684|HG03685|HG03686|HG03687|HG03689|HG03690|HG03691|HG03692|HG03693|HG03694|HG03695|HG03696|HG03697|HG03698|HG03702|HG03703|HG03705|HG03706|HG03708|HG03709|HG03711|HG03713|HG03714|HG03716|HG03717|HG03718|HG03720|HG03722|HG03727|HG03729|HG03730|HG03731|HG03733|HG03736|HG03738|HG03740|HG03741|HG03742|HG03743|HG03744|HG03745|HG03746|HG03750|HG03752|HG03753|HG03754|HG03755|HG03756|HG03757|HG03760|HG03762|HG03765|HG03767|HG03770|HG03771|HG03772|HG03773|HG03774|HG03775|HG03777|HG03778|HG03779|HG03780|HG03781|HG03782|HG03784|HG03785|HG03786|HG03787|HG03788|HG03789|HG03790|HG03792|HG03793|HG03796|HG03800|HG03802|HG03803|HG03805|HG03808|HG03809|HG03812|HG03814|HG03815|HG03817|HG03821|HG03823|HG03824|HG03826|HG03829|HG03830|HG03832|HG03833|HG03836|HG03837|HG03838|HG03844|HG03846|HG03848|HG03849|HG03850|HG03851|HG03854|HG03856|HG03857|HG03858|HG03861|HG03862|HG03863|HG03864|HG03866|HG03867|HG03868|HG03869|HG03870|HG03871|HG03872|HG03873|HG03874|HG03875|HG03882|HG03884|HG03885|HG03886|HG03887|HG03888|HG03890|HG03894|HG03895|HG03896|HG03897|HG03898|HG03899|HG03900|HG03902|HG03905|HG03907|HG03908|HG03910|HG03911|HG03913|HG03914|HG03916|HG03917|HG03919|HG03920|HG03922|HG03925|HG03926|HG03928|HG03931|HG03934|HG03937|HG03940|HG03941|HG03943|HG03944|HG03945|HG03947|HG03949|HG03950|HG03951|HG03953|HG03955|HG03960|HG03963|HG03965|HG03967|HG03968|HG03969|HG03971|HG03973|HG03974|HG03976|HG03977|HG03978|HG03985|HG03986|HG03989|HG03990|HG03991|HG03995|HG03998|HG03999|HG04001|HG04002|HG04003|HG04006|HG04014|HG04015|HG04017|HG04018|HG04019|HG04020|HG04022|HG04023|HG04025|HG04026|HG04029|HG04033|HG04035|HG04038|HG04039|HG04042|HG04047|HG04054|HG04056|HG04059|HG04060|HG04061|HG04062|HG04063|HG04070|HG04075|HG04076|HG04080|HG04090|HG04093|HG04094|HG04096|HG04098|HG04099|HG04100|HG04106|HG04107|HG04118|HG04131|HG04134|HG04140|HG04141|HG04144|HG04146|HG04152|HG04153|HG04155|HG04156|HG04158|HG04159|HG04161|HG04162|HG04164|HG04171|HG04173|HG04176|HG04177|HG04180|HG04182|HG04183|HG04185|HG04186|HG04188|HG04189|HG04194|HG04195|HG04198|HG04200|HG04202|HG04206|HG04209|HG04210|HG04211|HG04212|HG04214|HG04216|HG04219|HG04222|HG04225|HG04227|HG04229|HG04235|HG04238|HG04239|NA18486|NA18488|NA18489|NA18498|NA18499|NA18501|NA18502|NA18504|NA18505|NA18507|NA18508|NA18510|NA18511|NA18516|NA18517|NA18519|NA18520|NA18522|NA18523|NA18525|NA18526|NA18528|NA18530|NA18531|NA18532|NA18533|NA18534|NA18535|NA18536|NA18537|NA18538|NA18539|NA18541|NA18542|NA18543|NA18544|NA18545|NA18546|NA18547|NA18548|NA18549|NA18550|NA18552|NA18553|NA18555|NA18557|NA18558|NA18559|NA18560|NA18561|NA18562|NA18563|NA18564|NA18565|NA18566|NA18567|NA18570|NA18571|NA18572|NA18573|NA18574|NA18577|NA18579|NA18582|NA18591|NA18592|NA18593|NA18595|NA18596|NA18597|NA18599|NA18602|NA18603|NA18605|NA18606|NA18608|NA18609|NA18610|NA18611|NA18612|NA18613|NA18614|NA18615|NA18616|NA18617|NA18618|NA18619|NA18620|NA18621|NA18622|NA18623|NA18624|NA18625|NA18626|NA18627|NA18628|NA18629|NA18630|NA18631|NA18632|NA18633|NA18634|NA18635|NA18636|NA18637|NA18638|NA18639|NA18640|NA18641|NA18642|NA18643|NA18644|NA18645|NA18646|NA18647|NA18648|NA18740|NA18745|NA18747|NA18748|NA18749|NA18757|NA18853|NA18856|NA18858|NA18861|NA18864|NA18865|NA18867|NA18868|NA18870|NA18871|NA18873|NA18874|NA18876|NA18877|NA18878|NA18879|NA18881|NA18907|NA18908|NA18909|NA18910|NA18912|NA18915|NA18916|NA18917|NA18923|NA18924|NA18933|NA18934|NA18939|NA18940|NA18941|NA18942|NA18943|NA18944|NA18945|NA18946|NA18947|NA18948|NA18949|NA18950|NA18951|NA18952|NA18953|NA18954|NA18956|NA18957|NA18959|NA18960|NA18961|NA18962|NA18963|NA18964|NA18965|NA18966|NA18967|NA18968|NA18969|NA18970|NA18971|NA18972|NA18973|NA18974|NA18975|NA18976|NA18977|NA18978|NA18979|NA18980|NA18981|NA18982|NA18983|NA18984|NA18985|NA18986|NA18987|NA18988|NA18989|NA18990|NA18991|NA18992|NA18993|NA18994|NA18995|NA18997|NA18998|NA18999|NA19000|NA19001|NA19002|NA19003|NA19004|NA19005|NA19006|NA19007|NA19009|NA19010|NA19011|NA19012|NA19017|NA19019|NA19020|NA19023|NA19024|NA19025|NA19026|NA19027|NA19028|NA19030|NA19031|NA19035|NA19036|NA19037|NA19038|NA19041|NA19042|NA19043|NA19054|NA19055|NA19056|NA19057|NA19058|NA19059|NA19060|NA19062|NA19063|NA19064|NA19065|NA19066|NA19067|NA19068|NA19070|NA19072|NA19074|NA19075|NA19076|NA19077|NA19078|NA19079|NA19080|NA19081|NA19082|NA19083|NA19084|NA19085|NA19086|NA19087|NA19088|NA19089|NA19090|NA19091|NA19092|NA19093|NA19095|NA19096|NA19098|NA19099|NA19102|NA19107|NA19108|NA19113|NA19114|NA19116|NA19117|NA19118|NA19119|NA19121|NA19129|NA19130|NA19131|NA19137|NA19138|NA19141|NA19143|NA19144|NA19146|NA19147|NA19149|NA19152|NA19153|NA19159|NA19160|NA19171|NA19172|NA19175|NA19184|NA19185|NA19189|NA19190|NA19197|NA19198|NA19200|NA19201|NA19204|NA19206|NA19207|NA19209|NA19210|NA19213|NA19214|NA19222|NA19223|NA19225|NA19235|NA19236|NA19238|NA19239|NA19247|NA19248|NA19256|NA19257|NA19307|NA19308|NA19309|NA19310|NA19312|NA19314|NA19315|NA19316|NA19317|NA19318|NA19319|NA19320|NA19321|NA19323|NA19324|NA19327|NA19328|NA19331|NA19332|NA19334|NA19338|NA19346|NA19347|NA19350|NA19351|NA19355|NA19360|NA19372|NA19374|NA19375|NA19376|NA19377|NA19378|NA19379|NA19380|NA19383|NA19384|NA19385|NA19390|NA19391|NA19393|NA19394|NA19395|NA19397|NA19399|NA19401|NA19403|NA19404|NA19428|NA19429|NA19430|NA19431|NA19434|NA19435|NA19436|NA19437|NA19438|NA19439|NA19440|NA19443|NA19445|NA19446|NA19448|NA19449|NA19451|NA19452|NA19454|NA19455|NA19456|NA19457|NA19461|NA19462|NA19463|NA19466|NA19467|NA19468|NA19471|NA19472|NA19473|NA19474|NA19475|NA19625|NA19648|NA19649|NA19651|NA19652|NA19654|NA19655|NA19657|NA19658|NA19661|NA19663|NA19664|NA19669|NA19670|NA19676|NA19678|NA19679|NA19681|NA19682|NA19684|NA19700|NA19701|NA19703|NA19704|NA19707|NA19711|NA19712|NA19713|NA19716|NA19717|NA19719|NA19720|NA19722|NA19723|NA19725|NA19726|NA19728|NA19729|NA19731|NA19732|NA19734|NA19735|NA19740|NA19741|NA19746|NA19747|NA19749|NA19750|NA19752|NA19755|NA19756|NA19758|NA19759|NA19761|NA19762|NA19764|NA19770|NA19771|NA19773|NA19774|NA19776|NA19777|NA19779|NA19780|NA19782|NA19783|NA19785|NA19786|NA19788|NA19789|NA19792|NA19794|NA19795|NA19818|NA19819|NA19834|NA19835|NA19900|NA19901|NA19904|NA19908|NA19909|NA19913|NA19914|NA19916|NA19917|NA19920|NA19921|NA19922|NA19923|NA19982|NA19984|NA20126|NA20127|NA20274|NA20276|NA20278|NA20281|NA20282|NA20287|NA20289|NA20291|NA20294|NA20296|NA20298|NA20299|NA20314|NA20317|NA20318|NA20320|NA20321|NA20332|NA20334|NA20339|NA20340|NA20342|NA20346|NA20348|NA20351|NA20355|NA20356|NA20357|NA20359|NA20362|NA20412|NA20845|NA20846|NA20847|NA20849|NA20850|NA20851|NA20852|NA20853|NA20854|NA20856|NA20858|NA20859|NA20861|NA20862|NA20863|NA20864|NA20866|NA20867|NA20868|NA20869|NA20870|NA20872|NA20874|NA20875|NA20876|NA20877|NA20878|NA20881|NA20882|NA20884|NA20885|NA20886|NA20887|NA20888|NA20889|NA20890|NA20891|NA20892|NA20894|NA20895|NA20896|NA20897|NA20899|NA20900|NA20901|NA20902|NA20903|NA20904|NA20905|NA20906|NA20908|NA20910|NA20911|NA21086|NA21087|NA21088|NA21089|NA21090|NA21091|NA21092|NA21093|NA21094|NA21095|NA21097|NA21098|NA21099|NA21100|NA21101|NA21102|NA21103|NA21104|NA21105|NA21106|NA21107|NA21108|NA21109|NA21110|NA21111|NA21112|NA21113|NA21114|NA21115|NA21116|NA21117|NA21118|NA21119|NA21120|NA21122|NA21123|NA21124|NA21125|NA21126|NA21127|NA21128|NA21129|NA21130|NA21133|NA21135|NA21137|NA21141|NA21142|NA21143|NA21144)$/’ All_Combined_Individual_Data_RD23022018.txt > Caucasian_Individual_Data_RD26022018.txt

Comment: umm... why not use string comparison?

Comment: this is the most fearful regex pattern (this is self-flagellation)

Answer (score 6):

Seriously, that regular expression is ridiculous.

Instead, write the strings, one per line, to a simple text file and use

```
grep -v -w -F -f patternfile inputfile >outputfile
```

This will only output lines from `inputfile` that does not contain the strings listed in `patternfile`. The `-F` flag will cause `grep` to treat the strings as strings and not as regular expressions (this will probably make it use less memory too). The `-w` flag assures you that you will match whole words and not substrings of words (i.e. `NA21130` will only match `NA21130` and not `GNA21130` or `NA211301`).

If you want to specifically look for the string in column 5:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { pattern[$0] = 1; next } !pattern[$5]' patternfile inputfile >outputfile
```

This will first read the strings from `patternfile` into an array, indexed by the strings.  Then it will read `inputfile` and test whether the value in column 5 is an index in the array.  If it's not, the line is passed through.

---

Also note that on a POSIX system, the maximum allowed combined length of a command line and the current environment (all environment variables and their values) is guaranteed to be at least 4 KB. On most systems it's more or a lot more than this, but you should be prepared to get the error message `Argument list too long` when trying to execute commands like the 16 KB command line in the question.

Comment: +1. The awk answer is especially good.  You can also use `gsub()` to make it strip leading and trailing whitespace and everything after a `#`, and then skip empty lines. The `patternfile` would then support comments (including commenting out lines instead of just deleting them) and using blank lines to separate conceptually-related patterns from other groups of patterns.  I do this with `perl` all the time, and with `awk` occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with grep:

> grep –v –E ‘(HG00403|HG00404|HG00406|...(16 KB of terms)...|NA21142|NA21143|NA21144)’ < All_Combined_Individual_Data_RD23022018.txt > Caucasian_Individual_Data_RD26022018.txt

Comment: That is a different command though. It will match no matter where the string appears in the file. Also note that your commands (both this one and your original one) will also match sub-strings. So `NA21095` will also match `NA210955` (which is unlikely now, but might be possible in a few years given how quickly genomic data are being accumulated). By the way, you might find our sister site, [bioinformatics.se], interesting.